# How do I include a comma in an Apt pin definition?

Tags: configuration, special-characters, pinning

I'd like to create an Apt preference file with a pin definition that matches packages originating from `Google, Inc.`.

The following definition doesn't seem to be doing anything:

```
Package: *
Pin: release o=Google, Inc.
Pin-priority: 900
```

I suspect that the comma is causing problems. How can I escape it?

None of the following have worked:

- `release o="Google, Inc."`
- `release o='Google, Inc.'`
- `release o=Google\, Inc.`
- `release o=Google\\, Inc.`

Curiously, the following does match `Google, Inc.` successfully:

- `release o=Google? Inc.`

But this isn't the solution I'm looking for. I want to know how to match `Google, Inc.` without resorting to (precarious) wildcards.

More information:

```
$ apt-cache policy | grep -C 1 'Google, Inc.'
 500 http://dl.google.com/linux/earth/deb/ stable/main amd64 Packages
     release v=1.0,o=Google, Inc.,a=stable,n=stable,l=Google,c=main
     origin dl.google.com
 500 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable/main amd64 Packages
     release v=1.0,o=Google, Inc.,a=stable,n=stable,l=Google,c=main
     origin dl.google.com
$ grep Origin /var/lib/apt/lists/dl.google.com_*_Release
/var/lib/apt/lists/dl.google.com_linux_chrome_deb_dists_stable_Release:Origin: Google, Inc.
/var/lib/apt/lists/dl.google.com_linux_earth_deb_dists_stable_Release:Origin: Google, Inc.
```

Comment: Have you tried `o="Google, Inc."`, or `o='Google, Inc.'`?

Comment: Do you still experience the same issue?

Answer (score 1):

Not quite what you were trying to do but it may work as well for you, try:

`Pin: origin dl.google.com`

I settled on this after giving up trying to pin it by release and it has the same effect as long as you haven't any other repos from this host...

Answer (score 0):

If you escape the comma, the space should also be escaped, like in:

```
o=Google\,\ Inc.
```

Comment: Have you tested this? It doesn't appear to work for me.

Comment: I couldn't, my policies do not contain o= with whitespace, just a guess.