# Ubuntu 13.04 running really slow and Hanging

Tags: 13.04, nvidia

Up till recently I have been running 13.04 on my laptop very happily. This morning however, I turned on my laptop to find it running really slow. Takes 5 min to load a program and even then the program freezes and I have had 3 system hangs this morning already. The Unity Desktop appears to run ok but programs do not. 
Things I have tried so far: 
Checking for Propitiatory graphics drivers - none shown available (I have bumblebee running already). 
Using the recovery boot options from Grub to repair broken packages.

Recent changes - Updated computer, Installed some indicator applets which have worked fine for me before.

System Specs: Asus U36s, Intel Core i5-2450M 2.5GHz, 4GB RAM, Nvidia Geforce 610M-1GB, Dual boot Win7 & Ubuntu 13.04

I'm a bit of a noob with Ubuntu but am happy enough running stuff in terminal if you will advise me on what to run. I'm just a bit stuck on what do to fix this without a reinstall. 
Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: did you install or configure anything just before it started to slow down so much? and does windows still run normal?

Comment: I installed the indicator applets (indicator-multiload, indicator remindor, and hardware sensors indicator) last night and also updated the system

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you installed something from development repository? Check [these tips](https://sites.google.com/site/easylinuxtipsproject/fatalmistakes). If you really did this, try [this solution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/59443/how-can-i-revert-back-from-an-upgrade-to-the-proposed-repository) to revert to stable and security updates. Note that you have to edit the file corresponding to your release name.

Comment: Ok thanks for the tips. Having read that I think there is a high probability that it was some messing with UbuntuTweak that i did last night. I changed the login screen image and the logo image. I didn't think that that would have any effect on how programs run though?

Comment: Right reset the UbuntuTweak settings back to normal. Still no change.

Comment: Be sure not to use proposed repository.

Comment: Sorry been out of the contry for a couple of weeks. How do I check that I'm not using a proposed repository?

Comment: Settings -> Software Sources -> Updates