# How to downgrade plasma 5.6.4 to 5.5

Tags: kubuntu, kde, ppa, plasma

I installed via [the backports ppa](http://www.kubuntu.org/news/plasma-5-6-4-available-in-16-04-backports/) but experiencing pretty much bugs. Is there any way to downgrade?

Comment: Like that: http://askubuntu.com/questions/59443/how-can-i-revert-back-from-an-upgrade-to-the-proposed-repository/229663#229663

Answer (score 1):

You can use the programm **ppa-purge** to revert back to the current state. This is achieved via terminal-console:

`sudo apt-get install ppa-purge`

This installs the package.

Then make sure that the ppa-repository is ticked to "activated". One outline that is important, if the packages in the ppa-repository are newer than the ones you have installed, the programm fails, as it has to compare. Make sure that your system is up-to-date.

The correct command to revert is:

`sudo ppa-purge ppa:kubuntu-ppa/backports`

Then you are presented with a long list what packages are going to be removed/installed once you strike the "y" for yes. You can try to interpret the list ***before*** hitting the "y". If anything seems to be suspicious to you, just don't do it.

If you want to make sure no essential package is missing, reinstall, the meta-package after the purge:

`sudo apt-get install kubuntu-desktop`

And to make sure missing dependencies are resolved correctly:

`sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`

Last not least to mention: turn off "auto-login" if enabled. Enable "Start with empty session" via the systemsettings. If you downgrade, you may want to avoid hitting a Plasma-problem with your personal cache. When everything so far seemed to have been successful, do **not reboot yet**, but **logout** from the current session. Then use the keys `ALT+CTRL+F1` to come to a virtual terminal VT1 (ALT+F7 would bring you  back, just to mention).

There login with your user-name and password (not echoed), then proceed to clear the personal cache:

`rm -rf ~/.cache` (Compare twice that you type this correctly)

This command deletes all content of the personal cache and it's subfolders.

To restart the machine from VT1 then use `sudo reboot` and cross fingers.

Notice that the 1st start may be a bit delayed, as the personal cache needs to build up again, and the indexing (if enabled) may asks for it's tribute as well.

(/offtopic) It would be of personal interest, what the bugs were you encountered. I'm using the Kubuntu-backports-ppa and it *solved* numberous bugs for me, so maybe you can try the cache-cleaning beforehand. (offtopic/)

If anything is unclear for you, don't mind asking.

Answer (score 1):

I am adding this answer here for anyone for whom `ppa-purge` method didnt work.

For me, for some reason ppa-purge was unable to remove the ppa and downgrade the packages. I had to manually do it.

1. First go to `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`. This is a directory that contains all the PPA files.

   . Delete the PPA files for backports. In my case they were : `kubuntu-ppa-ubuntu-backports-bionic.list` and `kubuntu-ppa-ubuntu-backports-bionic.list.save`. (You may need to open the terminal and do sudo rm for this)
2. Remove plasma: `sudo apt remove plasma*`
3. Remove kdeplasma : `sudo apt remove kdeplasma*`
4. This might remove kde-runtime. So install it again. `sudo apt install kde-runtime`
5. Install plasma desktop again. `sudo apt install plasma-desktop`
6. Now it is time to reinstall everything you had deleted.
   `sudo apt install kdeplasma*`
   `sudo apt install plasma*`

   While doing this you may get errors like unmet-dependencies and broken packages. Every package that is broken, you need to reinstall it to previous version. In the error , you will get a list of packages that could not be installed. 
   So if one of the entry is something like:

   > [package1] : Depends: [package2] (>= [some number]) but [some number]ubuntu1 is to be installed...

All you have to do is reinstall package2.
     `sudo apt remove [package2]`
     `sudo apt install [package2]`

7. Now restart plasma shell
   `killall plasmashell`
   `kstart plasmashell`
   If you get errors like `kstart:command not found`, make sure you have installed `kde-runtime`.
   `sudo apt install kde-runtime`
8. Now it may appear as if in the system tray and start menu, everything is out of place , font is not proper etc. This should be fixed on rebooting. **But before you reboot** you should install login theme, else you might have problems logging back in during reboot.
   `sudo apt install sddm-theme-breeze`
9. `reboot`
10. Once you have rebooted, you can check the version of your shell to make sure you have successfully downgraded to stable version. `plasmashell -v`
11. Now you can remove unnecessary packages that might have been installed by doing `sudo apt autoclean`