# Audio problem after downgrading xenial-proposed

Tags: sound, updates, downgrade

I hade xenial-proposed updates activated and I started to have some troubles with evince. I deactivated the -proposed updates and I just followed the instructions of

[How can I revert back from an upgrade to the Proposed repository?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/59443/how-can-i-revert-back-from-an-upgrade-to-the-proposed-repository)

to downgrade to the xenial stable configurations and updates.

After rebooting my audio crackles ! I don't hear any sound, just crackles, even when ubuntu starts.

I followed the instructions on https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SoundTroubleshooting and everything seems fine, and now I don't know what to do.

Answer (score 0):

I just shut down a couple of times the system and now audio is working again, even though I do not get any ubuntu starting drum sound