# How to find what packages do not come from a repository?

Tags: apt

I have problem with one deb repository (specifically medibuntu.org) today - synaptic is not able to find repository indexes (and they are really not there - maybe due to yesterday's changes).

So I have the errors flying all over the place. I could just remove that repository - but I simply do not remember which packages came from it, so just removing it could screw my updates on some crucial package.

So, my question is - how do I find, which installed packages can not be found in any repository?

Comment: Does this help? http://askubuntu.com/questions/5976/how-can-i-list-all-packages-ive-installed-from-a-particular-ppa

Comment: Based on your distribution... sudo apt list --manual-installed | grep -v cosmic

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`aptitude` can do this query for you, with the `~o` ("o" for "obsolete") search:

```
aptitude search ~o
```

this lists the packages that can no longer be downloaded.

I don't think there's an `apt-cache search` equivalent, and I'm not sure about synaptic.

For more info on search terms with `aptitude`, check out the [section on search terms](http://algebraicthunk.net/~dburrows/projects/aptitude/doc/en/ch02s03s05.html) in the [aptitude reference guide](http://algebraicthunk.net/~dburrows/projects/aptitude/doc/en/index.html).

Comment: Seems that medibuntu contained sun-java6 package :( Thanks for your help!

Comment: Then this might be handy: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Java

Comment: you mean I can not bother about updates? :)

Comment: remember to escape the `~` in the shell!

Comment: Ysangkok: only if you have a user with a username of `o` :)

Answer (score 5):

Run Synaptic. In the lower left series of buttons, select "Status". The list above these buttons may have an entry "[Installed (local or obsolete)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/44930/what-does-local-or-obsolete-mean-in-synaptic)". When selected, this will show you all packages that were either installed locally (eg. from a downloaded `deb` file) or were installed via a repository but aren't listed any more. (There's no real way for Synaptic to tell the difference, hence they're grouped together.)

If you don't have any local or obsolete packages, this entry will not be present, so don't worry :)