# How to list installed packages in apt that are not backed by a repository?

Tags: apt, aptitude

I suppose you could build a list of all packages that would be installed if you started with an empty apt database and installed everything that `deborphan -a` currently tells you. Then compare that with what's currently installed.

The difference would be packages that cannot be retrieved automatically with the current list of repositories.

I've no idea where to start with that though.

Comment: -1 to justify duplicate. But this question has good unique answer for `apt-show-versions` and should be merged into [this older post](http://askubuntu.com/q/110758/37165) instead.