# How do I list all packages outside of the enabled repositories?

Tags: apt, package-management

I upgraded ubuntu, and since every PPA is disabled by default, I want to be able to list all packages that I have installed but aren't inside any enabled repositories.
I want a command (or a series of commands) that performs a similar function as `pacman -Qm` on ArchLinux.

Comment: I think apt dont have that support/feature AFAIK.

Comment: Or http://askubuntu.com/questions/110758/how-to-find-what-packages-do-not-come-from-a-repository