# List all packages that synaptic calls "local or obsolete" using command line

Tags: 18.04, package-management, synaptic

I seek a command line solution to list all packages that synaptic displays as "local or obsolete".

This [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/44934/243321) to  this [question](https://askubuntu.com/q/44930/243321) gives the command  `aptitude search ~o` which gives a partial list.  I suspect that other options after the `~` might help, but haven't found them documented.

Synaptic's list:
[image]

Output of `aptitude search ~o`:

```
$ aptitude search ~o
i   hexen2-data                     - Hexen II commercial data files            
i   hexen2-portals-data             - Hexen II Mission Pack: Portal of Praevus  
i   libdvdcss-dev                   - library for accessing encrypted DVDs - dev
i   libdvdcss2                      - library for accessing encrypted DVDs      
i   quake2-full-data                - Quake II data files                       
i   quake2-groundzero-data          - Quake II Mission Pack 2: Ground Zero data 
i   quake2-reckoning-data           - Quake II Mission Pack 1: The Reckoning dat
i   scangearmp2                     - ScanGear MP for Linux.
```

Note that the packages 'orphaned' when Canonical pulled updates to them out of the repos are not listed by this command. Neither is `pcmanfm` which I installed using `gdebi`.

What's a command I can run in the terminal to give me the same list as synaptic produces?

Comment: i know only half of the answer. For displaying local packages you can use `apt-mark showmanual`  Most of them are metapackages.

Comment: @user966203 thanks for your comment. On my system that command generates a giant list of packages, far more than are shown in the Synaptic list.